# Python action freezes the program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, threadpool

I have this little program I wrote, In it there is a class of methods, and a class that build the window (only one).

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
import socket
import platform ,sys
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import Queue
import threading

class Methods(object):
    def __init__(self):
         #TODO : implement
        pass

    def getHostName(self):
        try:
            return socket.gethostname()
        except:
            return "ERROR :Could'nt get Hostname"

    def getOperatingSystem(self):
        try:
            return platform.system() + " " + platform.release() + " " + platform.version() + " " + sys.getwindowsversion()[4]
        except:
            return "ERROR :Could'nt get Operating System"

    def getHotFixes(self,queue):
        try:
            startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
            startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            myProcess = subprocess.Popen(
                "wmic qfe get HotFixID, InstalledOn",
                stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                startupinfo = startupinfo)
            out, error = myProcess.communicate()
            full_list = out.splitlines()
            result = ""
            for item in full_list:
                if item != "" and item != " ":
                    result += "%s \n" % item

            out_number = len(result.splitlines()) - 1
            a =  "There Are %s Microsoft HotFixes Updates \n\n%s" % (out_number , result)
            queue.put(a)
        except:
            return "ERROR :Could'nt get HotFixes"


#VISUAL
#This class will have an instance of Methods and call every action by itself.
class MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('SAAP')
        self.root.geometry('610x440+100+100')
        #self.root.resizable(0,0)
        self.methods = Methods()

        def openHostName():
            disableAllButtons(self)
            result = self.methods.getHostName()
            print result
            self.textLabelString.set("Host Name")
            self.textBox.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.textBox.delete("1.0",END)
            self.textBox.insert(INSERT,result)
            self.textBox.config(state=DISABLED)
            enableAllButtons(self)

        def openOperatingSystem():
            disableAllButtons(self)
            result = self.methods.getOperatingSystem()
            print result
            self.textLabelString.set("Operating System")
            self.textBox.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.textBox.delete("1.0",END)
            self.textBox.insert(INSERT,result)
            self.textBox.config(state=DISABLED)
            enableAllButtons(self)

        def openHotFixes():
            queue = Queue.Queue()
            thread_ = threading.Thread(
                target = self.methods.getHotFixes,
                name='Thread1',
                args=[queue],
                )
            thread_.start()
            thread_.join()
            result = queue.get()
            disableAllButtons(self)
            self.textLabelString.set("Microsoft Hotfixes")
            self.textBox.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.textBox.delete("1.0",END)
            self.textBox.insert(INSERT,result)
            self.textBox.config(state=DISABLED)
            enableAllButtons(self)



        #items decleration
        self.actionLabel = Label(self.root, text = 'Actions',bg='blue',fg='white')
        self.button1 = Button(self.root, text = 'Host Name' , command=openHostName)
        self.button2 = Button(self.root, text = 'Operating System' , command = openOperatingSystem)
        self.button3 = Button(self.root, text = 'Microsoft HotFixes' , command = openHotFixes)
        self.button4 = Button(self.root, text = 'N4')
        self.button5 = Button(self.root, text = 'Fi5o')
        self.button6 = Button(self.root, text = 'C6y')
        self.button7 = Button(self.root, text = '7')
        self.button8 = Button(self.root, text = '8y')
        self.button9 = Button(self.root, text = 'R9s')
        self.button10 = Button(self.root, text = '10t')
        self.button11 = Button(self.root, text = 'I11s')
        self.textLabelString = StringVar()
        self.textLabel = Label(self.root,bg='black',fg='white',width=60,textvariable=self.textLabelString)
        self.textLabelString.set("Output")
        self.textBox = Text(self.root,width=52)
        self.textBox.insert(INSERT,"Here's the output")
        self.textBox.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.scrollBar = Scrollbar(self.root)
        self.scrollBar.config(command=self.textBox.yview)
        self.textBox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollBar.set)

        #items placing
        self.actionLabel.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+E+N+S,pady=5)
        self.button1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button2.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button3.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button4.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button5.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button6.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button7.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button8.grid(row=8,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button9.grid(row=9,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button10.grid(row=10,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.button11.grid(row=11,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=W+E)
        self.textLabel.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
        self.textBox.grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=11,pady=5)
        self.scrollBar.grid(row=1,column=2,rowspan=11,sticky=N+S)

        def disableAllButtons(self):
            self.button1['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button2['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button3['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button4['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button5['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button6['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button7['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button8['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button9['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button10['state'] = DISABLED
            self.button11['state'] = DISABLED

        def enableAllButtons(self):
            self.button1['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button2['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button3['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button4['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button5['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button6['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button7['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button8['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button9['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button10['state'] = NORMAL
            self.button11['state'] = NORMAL


def main():
    mainw = MainWindow()
    mainw.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now , My problem is when I press a button it needs to do something and then the output should appear on screen.
BUT, and here comes the but -- 
when the action takes a bit, it freezes the program until the action is done.
I want to make the program treat maybe the action as a different thread so it won't freeze.
I tried some stuff but it did not worked for me unfortunately ...

Any Help ?
Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to execute your actions in separate threads, however you need to implement a
mechanism for signaling to your main thread (where Tk's loop is running) when actions
are finished, and to get the result(s).

One approach is to have a proper Action class, creating thread objects ; you pass
the method to execute and its arguments, then you start the thread - beforehand,
you register a callback that will be called in your Tk loop when action is finished.
In order to pass results from the thread to the callback, a Queue can be used:

```
import functools

class Action(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, method, *args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.method=method
        self.args=args
        self.queue=Queue.Queue()
    def run(self):
        self.queue.put(self.method(*self.args))
    def register_callback(self, tkroot, callback):
        # to be called by Tk's main thread,
        # will execute the callback in the Tk main loop
        try:
            result = self.queue.get_nowait()
        except:
            # set a timer, to check again for results within 100 milliseconds
            tkroot.after(100, functools.partial(self.register_callback,
                                                tkroot, callback))
        else:
            return callback(result)
```

**EDIT:** modification of the original example to show how to apply this to the `getHotFixes`
method

As an example, here is how to change `getHotFixes` accordingly:

```
class Methods(object):
    ...
    def getHotFixes(self):
        try:
            startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
            startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            myProcess = subprocess.Popen("wmic qfe get HotFixID, InstalledOn",
                stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                startupinfo = startupinfo)
            out, error = myProcess.communicate()
            full_list = out.splitlines()
            result = ""
            for item in full_list:
                if item != "" and item != " ":
                result += "%s \n" % item

            out_number = len(result.splitlines()) - 1
            return "There Are %s Microsoft HotFixes Updates \n\n%s" % (out_number , result)
        except:
            return "ERROR :Could'nt get HotFixes"
```

Finally, in `MainWindow` you just need to call the `getHotFixes` method, register
a callback to do something useful with the result when it's finished using
`register_callback` and call `start()` to start the Action thread:

```
class MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        ...
        def openHotFixes():
            disableAllButtons(self)
            action = Action(self.methods.getHotFixes)
            action.register_callback(self.root, openHotFixesDone)
            action.start()

        def openHotFixesDone(result):
            self.textLabelString.set("Microsoft Hotfixes")
            self.textBox.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.textBox.delete("1.0",END)
            self.textBox.insert(INSERT,result)
            self.textBox.config(state=DISABLED)
            enableAllButtons(self)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not understand how to implement this into a real method. Can you please show me how to implement your work into my method getHotFixes() ? Beacuse it's the most heavy. Thanks!

Comment: I just modified the answer to show how to apply it to the getHotFixes. Tell me if it works. Those last changes are untested, in case of error hopefully you can sort it out - you get the idea.

Comment: Never Mind my friend! Got it working! Thanks alot!          EDIT: Thanks i got it before :) thanks alot!